# Cannot translate popup message when adding a product to the cart

Tags: ajax, magento-1.9, cart

If you add a product to the shopping cart, a message pops up on top saying "You've just added this product to the cart"

I would like to translate the message in french.

Now I have tried to find the string in the csv files, but cannot find it. I have tried to add the string to translate.csv but that does not work.

I tried inline translation, but no little book appears with the popup message, I have used the "Find In Files" option in Notepad++ but it doesn't find it anywhere, so I cannot change it. I tried template hints to see where it comes from, but here too, I don't see anything.

I am stuck and wonder where the string comes from. it must be somewhere. Right?

Answer (score 0):

If you have *translation.csv* file for your theme then by placing it there SHOULD work and one more thing do check in other theme translation files maybe it is overridden by any other translation file.